# Alter Table in onUpgrade

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I got a small problem with my onUpgrade function.
The Code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion<2){
        db.rawQuery("ALTER TABLE "+this.getTableName()+" ADD COLUMN "+COLUMNS.TIME+ " integer default 0;", null);
        db.rawQuery("ALTER TABLE "+this.getTableName()+" ADD COLUMN "+COLUMNS.DATE+ " integer default 0;", null);
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+this.getTableName()+ " SET "+COLUMNS.TIME+ "="+COLUMNS.TIME_OLD+";", null);
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+this.getTableName()+ " SET "+COLUMNS.DATE+ "="+COLUMNS.DATE_OLD+";", null);
    }
};
```

The onUpgrade function is obviously called right because I get the error:

> no such column: _timenew (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE TABLE_SCORE_NORMAL SET _timenew=_time;

I wonder why it is this way. If I try this manually on the console it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but you should call `execSql()` instead of `rawQuery()` if the statement isn't a query

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Weird it didn't bug already on ALTER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawQuery()` compiles the SQL but does not run it. You'll need to call one of the `moveTo...()` methods on the returned `Cursor` to run the compiled SQL.

`execSql()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Insert between ALTER and UPDATE:

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.beginTransaction();
```